# @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Username) not displaying textbox

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am new to ASP.NET MVC and learning it. I am using Asp.Net MVC Entity Framework. In my view called "Register", I am writing the following code

```
<div id="Reg_div"> 
     @using (Html.BeginForm("RegisterUser", "Register", FormMethod.Post))
    {
    <table>

           <tr>

            <td>
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Username)
            </td>

            <td>
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Username)
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Password)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Password)
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.FName)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.FName)
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.LName)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.LName)
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Address)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Address)
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Email)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Email)
            </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>

            <td>
                <input type="submit" name="name" value="Register" />
            </td>

        </tr>



    </table>
    }
</div>
```

[image]

Here is RegistrationModel.cs

```
namespace PTMatrix.Models
{
using System;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using System.Linq;

public partial class RegistrationModel : DbContext
{
    public RegistrationModel()
        : base("name=RegistrationModel")
    {
    }

    public virtual DbSet<User_reg> User_reg { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<User_reg>()
            .Property(e => e.LName)
            .IsUnicode(false);

        modelBuilder.Entity<User_reg>()
            .Property(e => e.FName)
            .IsUnicode(false);

        modelBuilder.Entity<User_reg>()
            .Property(e => e.Password)
            .IsUnicode(false);

        modelBuilder.Entity<User_reg>()
            .Property(e => e.Address)
            .IsUnicode(false);

        modelBuilder.Entity<User_reg>()
            .Property(e => e.Email)
            .IsUnicode(false);

        modelBuilder.Entity<User_reg>()
            .Property(e => e.Phone)
            .IsUnicode(false);
    }
}
```

}

User_reg.cs

```
namespace PTMatrix.Models
{
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using System.Data.Entity.Spatial;

public partial class User_reg
{
    [Key]
    public int Uid { get; set; }

    [StringLength(50)]
    public string LName { get; set; }

    [StringLength(50)]
    public string FName { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(50)]
    public byte[] Username { get; set; }

    [StringLength(50)]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    [StringLength(50)]
    public string Address { get; set; }

    [StringLength(50)]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [StringLength(50)]
    public string Phone { get; set; }
}
```

}

I am getting a very strange error in which Textbox for Username is not being displayed but all other textboxes are displayed. Am I missing something? Please help.

Comment: Can you post your entity?

Comment: @PM. I can see that there is no ModelBuilder.Entity for Username. but I am not sure why.

Comment: What about the structure of "User_reg" ? Can you post that class code?

Comment: @PM. Is it because of byte return type? If yes then why only that field is byte?

Comment: Actually, I checked in the database and the datatype of Username was varbinary. I will change it to Varchar ;)

Comment: And that will solve your issue :)

Comment: The `byte[]` for username property is uncommon. Usually it declared as `string` in model & `varchar`/`nvarchar` column in SQL table.

Answer (score 2):

from your `User_reg` you are defining your `Username` as `byte[]`, that is why `EditorFor` did not display textbox,
because by default, it does not know what to display for `byte[]`.

You have two options:

1. change from `byte[]` to something like `string` (it is weird that a username is byte[] anyway)
2. if `byte[]` is what you intended, then create an EditorTemplate 
   for byte (quite a lot of info about this on web, [such as this one](https://exceptionnotfound.net/asp-net-mvc-demystified-display-and-editor-templates/) ) 
   or use something like `TextboxFor` which explicit specify what you want to output